# Haskell - disable accompanying binding check haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, proof

I wan't to disable the function that checks for accompanying binding in Haskell.

The reason I want to do this is to be able to able to implement proof by contradiction. Following type signature does not have any binding, and should not have so.

```
zeroDoesNotEqualOne :: Refl Z (S Z) -> Bottom
```

There are no inhabitant to the type `Refl Z (S Z)`, and therefore there should be no binding.

In the above snippet the types mean what you would expect such that `S Z` is the Peano natural for 1 and `Refl` only has a single inhabitant of type `Refl a a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to: using the `EmptyCase` language extension, this statement is actually provable. Here is a self-contained file demonstrating it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase     #-}

module ZeroNeqOne where

data (==) a b where
  Refl :: a == a

data Nat where
  Z :: Nat
  S :: Nat -> Nat

zeroNeqOne :: Z == S Z -> a
zeroNeqOne p = case p of {}
```

Given that you were talking about theorem proving in the comments it got me thinking and it turns out we can play a little game Coq users like quite a bit: using a diagonal function at the type level. Cf. JF Monin's [Proof Trick: Small inversions](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~monin/Publis/Docs/coq2.pdf). This time we'll use the `TypeFamilies` extension. The idea to discard a contradictory `a == b` is to use a type-level function that will ask us to prove a trivial goal when presented with `a` and an impossible one when presented with `b`. And then use the proof of equality to transport the trivial result to the impossible one:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies  #-}

module ZeroNeqOneDiag where

import Data.Void

data (==) a b where
  Refl :: a == a

subst :: a == b -> p a -> p b
subst Refl pa = pa

data Nat where
  Z :: Nat
  S :: Nat -> Nat

type family Diag (n :: Nat) :: * where
  Diag 'Z     = ()
  Diag ('S n) = Void

newtype Diagonal n = Diagonal { runDiagonal :: Diag n }

zeroNeqOneDiag :: 'Z == 'S 'Z -> Void
zeroNeqOneDiag p = runDiagonal $ subst p (Diagonal ())
```

Comment: I tried that, but then following also compiles: `zeroNeqOne :: Z == Z -> a`, which it shouldn't (compiling like `ghci ZeroNeqOne.hs -XDataKinds -fwarn-incomplete-patterns -Werror`).

Comment: It seems to be [a bug in the coverage checker](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10746). So for now you'll need to be careful when using empty-case. That being said, it's not more dangerous than having type signatures with no accompanying definition like you requested.

Comment: The hope was that I could achieve this using no accompanying binding, also with a compile time error when there is a pattern. I guess realt theorem provers a preferred when doing serious stuff anyways. But thanks!

Comment: You talking about theorem proving got me thinking and it turns out that we can use `TypeFamilies` to write a nice solution! See my edit.